# Compatible maps in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Our teacher told us to make three maps  $\left ( U, φ \right ), \left ( V, ψ \right ), \left ( W, χ \right )$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left \{φ,ψ \right\}$ and $\left \{ψ,χ\right\}$ are differentiably compatible, but $\left \{φ,χ\right\}$ aren't.

Two maps $\left ( U, φ \right ), \left ( V, ψ \right )$ to be differentiably compatible means that the functions:

$$φ\circ ψ^{-1}: ψ(U\cap V)\rightarrow φ(U\cap V)$$
$$ψ\circ φ^{-1}: φ(U\cap V)\rightarrow ψ(U\cap V)$$
are $\mathcal{C^\infty}$, i.e. infinite times differentiable.

I can't see how this is going to happen, because when you compose two $\mathcal{C^\infty}$ functions the outcome is $\mathcal{C^\infty}$. Am I missing something? Do you have any idea how to proceed? Thank you very much!

Comment: **Hint**: A composition of smooth maps is smooth, but the _inverse_ of a smooth bijection (even a polynomial map) may fail to be even once differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $\varphi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $\varphi(x) = x$ and $\psi:  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \to \mathbb R$, $\psi (x) = \tan x$, $\chi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $\chi (x) = x^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd like to ask though: Isn't it sufficient to take $ψ(x)=x$ with the same domain as you proposed?